# PipelineDB for OLTP and Streaming

Tags: pipelinedb

I read that PipelineDB is a drop-in replacement for Postgresql.  Can I run my standard OLTP data on it without any performance repucussions then?

Answer (score 0):

Jeff from PipelineDB here. PipelineDB is a superset of PostgreSQL so it can do everything PostgreSQL can do with the addition of the streaming functionality we've added, so yes, to answer your question. =)

Check out our technical docs:

http://docs.pipelinedb.com/

and find us on Gitter if you have any questions:

https://gitter.im/pipelinedb/pipelinedb